# Release Management > DACPAC - Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow

Tags: deployment, sql-server-data-tools, ms-release-management, dacpac

**ISSUE:**

Unable to deploy a DACPAC via Powershell script. This script works on approximately 20 other database servers that have been configured for release management.

**WORKING ENVIRONMENT:**

1. Windows Server 2008 R2
2. Powershell 2.0
3. SQL Server 2008 R2 64 bit
4. Visual Studio Premium 2012 Update 4
5. SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012
6. Release Management Deployer for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

**NOT WORKING ENVIRONMENT**:

1. Windows Server 2008 R2
2. Powershell 2.0
3. SQL Server 2012 64 bit
4. Visual Studio Premium 2012 Update 4
5. SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012
6. Release Management Deployer for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4

**COMMAND:**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\sqlpackage.exe
  /Action:Publish
  /SourceFile:"\\<Server>\Builds\<BuildDefinition>\<BuildNumber>\Databases\Arsenal\Arsenal.dacpac"
  /Profile:"\\<Server>\Builds\<BuildDefinition>\<BuildNumber>\Deployment\Configuration\Databases\Publish_DEFAULT.xml"
  /p:TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings="True"
  /v:BuildNumber="<BuildNumber>"
```

where:

`Publish_DEFAULT.xml` contains the following keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configurations>
  <Properties>
    <Property key="IncludeCompositeObjects" value="True" />
    <Property key="ScriptDatabaseOptions" value="True" />
    <Property key="BlockOnPossibleDataLoss" value="False" />
    <Property key="DropObjectsNotInSource" value="True" />
    <Property key="DropRoleMembersNotInSource" value="True" />
    <Property key="DropPermissionsNotInSource" value="True" />
    <Property key="DeployDatabaseInSingleUserMode" value="True" />
    <Property key="BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges" value="False" />
    <Property key="GenerateSmartDefaults" value="True" />
    <Property key="TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings" value="True" />
  </Properties>
  <SQLCmdVariables>
    <SQLCmdVariable key="BuildNumber" value="UNKNOWN" />
    <SQLCmdVariable key="DeployLoadTestData" value="False" />
    <SQLCmdVariable key="DeployPurgeData" value="False" />
  </SQLCmdVariables>
</Configurations>
```

**LOG**:

Publishing to database 
  Initializing deployment (Start)
  Initializing deployment (Failed)
  An unexpected failure occurred: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow..

> Unhandled Exception: System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation
>   resulted in an overflow.
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean
>   encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean&
>   marsCapable)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>        at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions)
>        at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>        at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)
>        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.<OpenConnection>b__0()
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.<>c__DisplayClass4.<ExecuteAction>b__3(RetryState
>   retryState)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction[R](Func`2
>   func, Nullable`1 token)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Action`1
>   action, Nullable`1 token)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableSqlConnection.OpenConnection()
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.OpenConnection(String
>   connectionString, Boolean useRetry)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.OpenConnection(SqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   csb, Action`1 usingConnection, Predicate`1 catchException, Boolean
>   useRetry)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Common.SqlClient.ReliableConnectionHelper.GetServerAndDatabaseVersion(String
>   connectionString, ServerAndDatabaseInfo& info)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SqlDatabaseSchemaProviderFamily.DetermineDatabaseSchemaProvider(String
>   connectionString)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.GetProviderType(DatabaseSchemaProviderFamily
>   connectionSniffer, String connectionString, Type& providerType,
>   Boolean& validDataSource)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentEndpointServer.OnInit(ErrorManager
>   errors, String targetDBName)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeployment..ctor(SqlDeploymentConstructor
>   constructor)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Deployment.SqlDeploymentConstructor.ConstructServiceImplementation()
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.CreatePackageToDatabaseDeployment(String
>   connectionString, IPackageSource packageSource, String
>   targetDatabaseName, DacAzureDatabaseSpecification creationDefaults,
>   DacDeployOptions options, ErrorManager errorManager)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<>c__DisplayClass5.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__1()
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Dac.OperationLogger.Capture(Action
>   action)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.<>c__DisplayClass3.<CreatePlanInitializationOperation>b__0(Object
>   operation, CancellationToken token)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.Operation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext
>   context)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.ReportMessageOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext
>   context)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext
>   context)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.CompositeOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext
>   context)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DeployOperation.Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.IOperation.Run(OperationContext
>   context)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.OperationExtension.Execute(IOperation operation, DacLoggingContext loggingContext, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.InternalDeploy(IPackageSource
>   packageSource, Boolean isDacpac, String targetDatabaseName,
>   DacAzureDatabaseSpecification creationDefaults, DacDeployOptions
>   options, CancellationToken cancellationToken, DacLoggingContext
>   loggingContext)
>        at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.DacServices.Deploy(DacPackage package, String targetDatabaseName, Boolean upgradeExisting, DacDeployOptions
>   options, Nullable`1 cancellationToken)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__0(DacServices
>   service)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.ExecuteDeployOperation(String
>   connectionString, String filePath, MessageWrapper messageWrapper,
>   Boolean sourceIsPackage, Boolean targetIsPackage, Func`1
>   generateScriptFromPackage, Func`2 generateScriptFromDatabase)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.DacServiceUtil.DoDeployAction(DeployArguments
>   parsedArgs, Action`1 writeError, Action`2 writeMessage, Action`1
>   writeWarning, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.DoDeployActions(CommandLineArguments
>   parsedArgs)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.PerformAction(CommandLineArguments
>   parsedArgs)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Run(String[] args)
>        at Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.CommandLineTool.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)

**ADDITIONAL COMMENT:**

The only different between the two environments is the version of SQL Server ... However, I do have a server with SQL Server 2012 that is working!

I ran the Powershell script as the identity of the service: Microsoft Deployment Agent ... same log file error; however, sqlpackage.exe is throwing the following error:

Problem signature:
   Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
   Problem Signature 01: sqlpackage.exe
   Problem Signature 02: 12.0.2743.1
   Problem Signature 03: 5438200c
   Problem Signature 04: System.Data
   Problem Signature 05: 4.0.30319.18408
   Problem Signature 06: 52310bef
   Problem Signature 07: 28b2
   Problem Signature 08: 6e
   Problem Signature 09: System.OverflowException
   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
   Locale ID: 1033
   Additional Information 1: d90e
   Additional Information 2: d90ee7d582c41ae7b6b96ca9c0463ab1
   Additional Information 3: 5e41
   Additional Information 4: 5e414a69026c10f11cc9c0b8e675c3aa

Comment: This is definitely an SSDT problem, not an RM problem... can you force-reinstall SSDT?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to publish the DACPAC directly how about generating a change script (check box option from the publish profile) and running the T-SQL that is generated against the database? Another option would be to open a command prompt at the sqlpackage.exe folder and run the command directly to see if that gives a clearer error message. Also, does running the publish profile directly against the database work? Visual Studio might shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1):

**ISSUE**:

This server was upgraded to SQL Server 2012 from SQL Server 2005 & enabled for DACPAC deployments (SSDT) via Release Management.  The upgrade steps were different from all other working database servers.  SSDT & RM were installed after SQL Server 2012 (not before)

**RESOLUTION**:

Rebuilt the database server with the following steps:

- Add domain users & groups to local group: Administrators (Restart)
- Add role:

  - Web Server (IIS) (Restart)
- Add features:

  - Desktop Experience (Restart)
  - Remote Server Administration Tools
  - SMTP Server
  - SNMP Services
  - Windows Powershell Integrated Scripting Environment (ISE)
  - Windows Process Activation Service
  - WinRM IIS Extension
- Install Window Updates (Restart)
- Install Virtual CloneDrive
- Install & confgure Release Management Deployer for Visual Studio 2013 Update 4
- Register server: DEVSQL2 with Release Management server
- Configure powershell (set-executionpolicy remotesigned)
- Install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for Visual Studio 2012
- Install Window Updates (Restart)
- Install SQL Server 2005 (64 bit) (Default instance)
- Install Server 2005 Enterprise (64 bit) Update 4 (Default instance)
- Install Window Updates (Restart)
- Configure SQL Server Surface Area
- Configure SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)
- Configure "default" directories
- Move tempdb files
- Create "standard" logins/roles
- Restore "golden" databases
- RM deployment of a TFS project - **PASSED**
- Install SQL Server 2012 Enterprise (64 bit) (Default Instance)
- Install Window Updates (Restart)
- RM deployment of a TFS project - **PASSED**